# Python go to def

Tags: python

Hi there
First of all just let me say that I'm new in Python and this is for a school work so this should be done without advanced programing and global functions. Using Python 2.6.6 and WingIDE 101

I need a program to present the user with a menu. The user must pick an option and accordingly to is pick the program does what the user wants.

For example, in the code bellow (its not the actual code), if the user picks 1 it goes to the sum() function.

```
def menu():
    print "What do you want? "
    print " 1 for sum"
    print " 2 for subtraction"
    pick = raw_input("please insert 1 or 2 ")
    if pick == "1":
       return sum()
    if pick == "2":
       return subtraction()
    else:
        menu()
menu()

def sum():
    return 8 + 4
def subtraction():
    return 8 - 4
```

I what to know how do I send, after my pick, the program to execute an determined definition.

Thanks

P.S. - running this gives me this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/wingide-101-3.2/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 12, in 
  File "/usr/lib/wingide-101-3.2/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 7, in menu
TypeError: sum expected at least 1 arguments, got 0

Comment: Try to launch your program on command line: <path-to-python>/python.exe <path-to-your-file>/yourfile.py

Comment: What you have will work if you more the second `menu()` call -- just before `def sum()` -- to the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong with this, so we will take up one by one.

`sum` is a built-in function in Python. So you cannot name your function `sum`. You have to call yourself something else, like `sum_foo`. Or `_sum`.

Also, your code is executed from top to bottom. So if you are calling a function say X in a function like Y.

```
def f():
        y()
f()  
def y():
        print 'Y called'
```

Results in this error:

```
NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

Because at your program runs, it is not aware of `y` because the `y` has not been declared at that point, since the program jumps to `f()`.

To fix this, you would do:

```
def f():
        y()    
def y():
        print 'Y called'            
f()
```

Also, call the function as `func_name()` and not `return func`. And since in your `sum` and `subtraction`, you are returning the values, save them in some variable and print them, or print them directly.

```
def sum():
    return 8 + 4
```

No output

```
def sum():
    print 8 + 4
```

Comment: And follow Falmarri's solution.

Comment: `sum` is not a keyword. It's the name of a built-in function, so you really shouldn't use this name for yourself - but it's not a keyword. Not even a reserved word. Otherwise good answer, but I've seen the (wrong) phrase "<builtin name> is a keyword" several times now.

Comment: Favolas, if the answer meets your requirements, consider accepting it using the big green tick in front of it!

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you're using the sum function before you declare it. it should raise a NameError, but the sum function is a builtin so you're calling that func ( that requires at least one argument) and not the func you've written...

to pass through you can call menu() after declaring the sum and subtraction func

ps it's not a good idea to overwrite python's builtin function..change name to your func, **and** call menu later, or you will get a NameError

Answer (score 0):

sum is a builtin at the point you're calling menu(). If you move this call after defining sum and substraction, it won't give you this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please place the sum and subtraction functions above the menu() function definition. You are calling into the built-in sum(iterable[, start]) function provided by python.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the call to `menu()` in a `if __name__ == '__main__:'` block. At the bottom of your code, just add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

This will help prevent using variables before they're defined.